# gcc/gfortran compiler flag/option to stop generation of any floating point instruction

Tags: gcc, floating-point, gfortran

I am doing some analysis using PIN/LLVM and I was wondering if there is anyway to switch off the generation of floating point x87 co-processor instructions such as FMUL, FLD etc.

Essentially something that could be easily done via a compiler flag etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the -msoft-float switch?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I simply did not check for a long time, but  I will look into this. For my own, I was able to find a coressponding non-floating point source code version which was logically the same